# R/exams NOPS generates documents in Times New Roman, which then fail during scanning

Tags: r, r-exams

I have been using r/exams in some of my last exams and everything has worked fine. This semester, however, r/exams seems to generate the exams in Times New Roman instead of Helvetica, which messes with the character recognition in the scanning process.

Even the minimal example, produces this behavior:

```
library("exams")
myexam <- list("cholesky.Rnw")
set.seed(403)
ex1 <- exams2nops(myexam, n = 1,
              dir = "nops_pdf", name = "demo", date = "2015-07-29",
              points = c(1), showpoints = TRUE)
```

Does anyone have any idea what could have gone wrong? How do I see the intermediate steps? I get no error messages.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the package, but there are a lot of options in `?exams2nops`, have you pored over this? A quick glance shows: "Note that the font in the PDF must not be modified for the reading step
  to work reliably. (A sans-serif font is used and hence the \code{sfmath}
  LaTeX package is also used - if it is installed.)", perhaps your latex installation is missing `sfmath`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Something was missing in my TinyTex installation. It was not 
    sfmath. I moved to MacTex and it works again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from R/exams version 2.3-2 (the current CRAN version at the time of writing) it is enforced that the digits that need to be scanned are always in Helvetica (`\fontfamily{phv}`) even if the font is switched for the rest of the document.

However, in a plain TinyTeX installation, i.e., after running just `tinytex::install_tinytex()` the Helvetica font is not installed yet. Just setting `\fontfamily{phv}` is not enough for TinyTeX to realize that an additional package needs to be installed (`psnfss`). Therefore, I have modified the devel version of `exams` on R-Forge to explicitly include `\usepackage{helvet}`. This will trigger the automatic installation of `psnfss` in TinyTeX. Installing version 2.3-5 should thus resolve the problem: `install.packages("exams", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`. This will also be released to CRAN in the next days.

Moreover, just for future reference, I went through the source code of `exams2nops()` to check what packages we use. Partly for historical reasons there are quite a few. Possibly these could also be streamlined.

- Basic tools: graphicx, color, amsmath, amssymb, latexsym.
- For compatibility with `Sweave`: verbatim, url, fancyvrb, ae.
- Layout etc.: multicol, a4wide, pdfpages, chngpage.
- Fonts: `helvet`, `sfmath`.
- For compatibility with LaTeX produced by `pandoc` from Markdown: booktabs, longtable, eurosym, textcomp.

Comment: Since **exams** uses `tools::texi2dvi()`, it cannot take full advantage of **tinytex** and TinyTeX. If you switch to `tinytex::latexmk()`, missing LaTeX packages will be automatically installed in TinyTeX.

Comment: @YihuiXie Thanks for pointing this out, I finally have time to work on this. I want to enable a switch between `tools::texi2dvi()` and `tinytex::latexmk()` in **exams**. Is `if(requireNamespace("tinytex"))` a good enough condition for deciding this? Shouldn't I test whether `tinytex` is really fully installed, i.e., check whether `tinytex::install_tinytex()` was actually run as well? Any hints appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to detect if TinyTeX (the LaTeX distribution) is installed. `tinytex::latexmk()` doesn't require the LaTeX distribution to be TinyTeX: https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#other-latex-distributions `tinytex::latexmk()` does most of the things that `tools::texi2dvi()` does, with one additional feature (i.e. automatically install missing LaTeX packages if possible). So `if (requireNamespace('tinytex'))` is enough.

Comment: Thanks, very much appreciated! I've committed this now to the devel version on R-Forge. Andre, if you want to give `tinytex` another try, you can get the devel version with `install.packages("exams", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`. If the "tinytex" package is installed, it wil be used automatically. Worked very smoothly for me!

Comment: Damn... Reinstalled Tinytex. Now I have the same problem again. 
Installing MacTex and removing TinyTex solved the problem. 
Installing TinyTex again creates this problem. I have no idea how to debug this. Is there a way of seeing the "source.tex" ?

Comment: In `exams2pdf()` and hence also `exams2nops()` you can set the `texdir=` argument to some directory where the tex files should be compiled. These can then be used for debugging afterwards.

Comment: I just tried this on a completely fresh Windows machine and could replicate your problem. Apparently, I cannot assume that fontfamily `phv` is just available in TeXLive. But after running `tinytex::tlmgr_install("psnfss")` everything worked for me. Can you confirm that? If so, I only need to find out what I need to include in the .tex file so that `tinytex` resolves this dependency on its own. Probably `usepackage{helvet}`.

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly. It would be great if you could confirm (or disconfirm) whether this also works for you.